# Are these two sensible and related or unrelated ways of regarding a logic system as a programming language?

Tags: programming-languages, logic, types-and-programming-languages

When I am trying to understand logic programming languages e.g. Prolog, I am immediately confused by the following two ways of relating logic systems and programming languages or type systems.

1. In *Types and Programming Languages* by Pierce, Section 9.4
   *Curry–Howard correspondence* on p109  has a table

   [image]

   Does it mean that a logic system is a programming language, where

   - types are propositions and
   - values of a type are proofs of the proposition?
2. On the other hand, a logic system is described in a formal language
   that defines what a logic expression is. Can we view a logic system
   (e.g. the first order predicate logic system) as a programming
   language, where

   - it has two types: Boolean type and function type, and
   - Each logic expression without a variable has Boolean type, so can be evaluated to a truth value.  Each logic expression with any
     variable has Boolean function type, so its application to truth
     values for its variables can be evaluated to a truth value?

Are the above two views of a logic system as a programming language completely unrelated/orthogonal, or are they the same or can they be unified?

Thanks.

Comment: In (2), you should not regard those boolean-valued functions as computable functions that programmers write, because there are non-computable ones. Hence this relationship between programming languages and logic is broken.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean that a logic system is a programming language, where types are propositions and values of a type are proofs of the proposition?

Not necessarily, being both (logic systems and programming language) formal languages, there certainly is a certain degree of isomorphism between the two concepts, this translates into the fact that we can encode a logical system through a programming language and develop algorithms to identify proofs of the theorems of our logical system.

If you are interested in the similarities between logical propositions and types, I strongly suggest you take a look at [Homotopy type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_type_theory#Computer_programming).

Comment: Thanks. See my clarification of my questions.

Comment: I am mainly wondering if the two views of a  logic system are related or not, and if the second view (from mine) is sensible.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between the two is related to intuistionistic logic vs. classical logic. When you add sufficiently powerful versions of the excluded middle law to Curry-Howard-style type systems, you can translate between propositions (types of sort `Prop`, which are inhabited if and only if they are provable) and Boolean values at will. Check out [the list of excluded middle/proof irrelevance laws available in Coq](https://github.com/coq/coq/wiki/The-Logic-of-Coq) for a jumping-off point.